# Why Blender 3.x videos not running on mobile browser?

Tags: export, video

I'm making a video for a website. I use MPEG4/H.264 and WebM/VP9 with resolution of 4320x1080 and 30fps but none of these videos are running on mobile browsers (Chrome, Mozilla, Edge, Opera) but on all desktop browsers. I imported the MPEG4 into Davinci Resolve and exported it again with MPEG4/H.264. Now they run everywhere except on mobile Edge. Also the file size from DR has doubled in size. But in DR the max resolution in my case is limited to 3840x960. In the html5 video tag I use the attributes

```
muted="" autoplay="" loop=""
```

Has someone an idea what I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks...

Comment: Do video files not created with Blender work? Or is just blender renders?

Comment: I'd blame it on the resolution, I know of no mobile device with a screen size that large, browsers are probably limited in this area. This doesn't seem to be an issue with Blender, this sounds off topic here.

Comment: Yes, videos created by DR are working (but I did yet not tried with exactly this resolution). Why is the file in DR with the same settings doubled in size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem so that the resolution 4320x1080 is not working. Maybe 4320 is too high, no idea. With 2160x1080 everthing is fine.